# MySQL 5.1 doesn't let me use declare in limits. I tried all the alternative methods and nothing worked and I cannot update MYSQL version

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL 5.1 doesn't let me use declared variable in limit. I tried all the alternative methods and nothing worked and I cannot update MYSQL version. Is there any other way I can run this query without error in MySql 5.1. I tried the same query in MySql 5.6 and above and it's working fine.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE event `cleaner` ON schedule every 7 day enable do
BEGIN
DECLARE `logCount` int(11);
SET `logCount` = (Select count(*) from `eventlogs`) - 5000;
DELETE FROM `eventlogs` ORDER BY `EventID` ASC LIMIT `logCount`;
END;
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'logCount;
END' at line 5

Comment: Do you want to keep up to 5000 rows?

Comment: I want to only keep latest 5000 rows and delete the old logs. EventID is autoincremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the 5001th greatest `EventID` and then delete all that are smaller or equal:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE `lastEventID` int(11);
    SET `lastEventID` = (
        Select `EventID`
        from `eventlogs`
        ORDER BY `EventID` DESC
        LIMIT 1
        OFFSET 5000
    );
    DELETE FROM `eventlogs` WHERE `EventID` <= `lastEventID`;
END;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. You're a savior. I was stuck in this for hours. Thank you.